# JQuery Accordion is not loading dynamically through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-accordion

**UPDATED:**
I am creating JQuery accordion dynamically which is populated by ajax data. 
Accordion is created properly on left side bar:

[image: Accordion]

When a new record has been created it has been added in accordion data but  it disturbs my accordion you can see below image in left side bar:

[image]

And when I refresh the page every thing looks fine like first image. My requirement is to not refresh the page and make accordion work. 
**Note: I put some alerts where accordion is calling and alerts are displaying more then three times unexpectedly. How can i restrict this calling ? If i may restrict this calling then my problem will be resolved ! OR suggest me to bind div with on load function/event so that it may run to a binned function accordingly**
I also go through these two questions [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868192/dynamically-adding-and-refreshing-elements-to-the-accordion-widget-in-jquery-ui) , [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373268/jquery-ui-accordion-not-working-with-ajax-loaded-content) but it didn't help me out!

Here is the code:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "/categories",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
          var content = "";

          for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            content += '<label class="categoryLables" id="">' + data[i].title + '</label>';

            content += '<div>';
            content += '<div>';
            content += '<ul>';

            for (j = 0; j < data[i].boards.length; j++) {

              content += '<li>';
              content += "<a href='/#categories/" + data[i].id + "/boards/" + data[i].boards[j].id + "'>";



              content += data[i].boards[j].name;
              content += '</a>';
              content += '</li>';
            }

            content += '</ul>';
            content += '</div>';
            content += '</div>';

          }

          alert("1");
          $("#category-navigation").html(content);
          alert("2");
          $('#category-navigation').accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            active: false,
            collapsible: true
          });
         alert("3");
        }
      });

> HTML:
```

```html
<div class="myNavigation">

  <div id="category-navigation">


  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When u call jQuery Accordion on a particular element, it works by adding certain classes to parent and then corresponding child elements to perform accordion functionality; which is already defined in the jQuery.

Since your data is dynamic and being loaded by ajax request, it may be the case that the accordion function is being called too early than the data is loaded and so that it is unable to apply proper classes to corresponding elements.

So, to solve this, you need to change your code a bit:

**remove** `<div id="category-navigation">` from **HTML**

```
<div class="myNavigation">
   <div id="category-navigation"> <!-- remove this div only --> 
   </div>
</div>
```

and generate it dynamically through jQuery as you are already doing with the rest of the code.

```
content += '<div id="category-navigation">'
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
...
...
...
}
content += '</div>';
```

Also, set the HTML of **myNavigation** instead of **#category-navigation**. Do this:

```
$(".myNavigation").html(content);
```

Now when you'd apply `$('#category-navigation').accordion`, it would work as it is being called after the population of dynamic data.

Comment: Thank you. just not sure why, but remvoe the <div id="category-navigation"> from HTML is the key.