# jQuery-UI scripts stop working after .load() in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am currently working on a dynamic survey form that would ask a customer what kind of product he wants and then display relevant products from our e-shop. Kind of like searching by parameters, but more personal.

Now I tried doing it by loading each page of form from individual .php files that are meant to replace certain div on my page to avoid having to reload whole page.

I am using, or rather I am TRYING to use jQuery UI widgets, but they stop working when I load the next page using `.load('url')` function. Console outputs error, at widget initialisation stating `$(...).slider is not a function(…)`

My individual pages look something like this

```
<style>
    #some styling relevant for the widgets
</style>
<script>


jQuery( function() {
    $('#back-button').click(function(){
          $('#formular-content').load('/eshop/formular/1.php') //this is how I load the pages
    });
    $('#next-button').click(function(){
          $('#formular-content').load('/eshop/formular/3.php') 
    });
//also these buttons work, so the whole <script> area seems... usable ?

//code copypasted from http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
          range: true,
          min: 0,
          max: 500,
          values: [ 75, 300 ],
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
          }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
          " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });
</script>
    <p>
      <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
      <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
    </p>

    <div id="slider-range"></div>
    <a id="back-button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" href="#">back</a>
    <a id="next-button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" href="#">back</a>
```

The whole thing is inside `<div>` in page which I load stuff into.

As I said in title, I am doing this in wordpress, so I have jquery and jquery-ui properly enqueued, it actually works on the first page which is identical for testing purposes. Also it is regular wordpress page created in admin panel and I had button and slider functions in functions.js file which is also properly enqueued in theme functions file.

So my question is, how do I make the scripts work after the `.load()`. I've read something about `$.getScript()` and thought to load jQuery UI files but I am not entirely sure how to make it work with WP and also if it's not being redundant, loading the same file over and over again. I am fairly new to these internet programming languages... especially to integrating them with WP.

Also if anyone has other ideas how I might do the whole form in different, better/easier way, I am open to any ideas.

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought this was Wordpress related, turns out it's not.

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373268/jquery-ui-accordion-not-working-with-ajax-loaded-content)

TL;DR

Add jQuery UI widgets initialization in `<script>` part of loaded .php document like this

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
   $('.accordion').accordion({
      heightStyle: "content",
      active: false,
      collapsible: true
   });

})
</script>
```

I didn't use `jQuery(document).ready` event and there was the problem.

Thanks [Guruprasad Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065039/guruprasad-rao) for your time on TeamViewer :)

Answer (score 0):

`$(...).slider is not a function(…)` error specifically states that you have written this code before loading reference to the `jquery-ui.js` file. So whatever script loading you have, put it before writing your `plugin` initialisation.

For the events to not work on dynamically loaded page through `.load` below would be the possible cause:

- Your dynamically loaded page's element might not have events attached to it, as in `.slider`, since it is loaded after the plugin has been initialised.

So, you need to have a `callback function` after your `.load` so that you can re-initialise on the newly loaded elements.

**Callback function**

```
$('#back-button').click(function(){
     $('#formular-content').load('/eshop/formular/1.php',function(){
          $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
               range: true,
               min: 0,
               max: 500,
               values: [ 75, 300 ],
              slide: function( event, ui ) {
                 $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
              }
          });
          //initialise anything here as in .slider() to the `element` which is loaded through ajax.
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not using any plugin, I am using enqueued functions.js to initialize those widgets, which work on the first page, then I load next page and they don't work anymore. I tried your code, but it's still the same. When the second page loads, console outputs  $(...).slider is not a function(…)

Comment: Can you show the order of scripts your are loading or anyway where you can show full code?

Comment: in theme's function.php I enqueue `functions.js, jquery, jquery-ui-core, and all jquery-ui-___  widgets`, then in `functions.js` I call `$( "#slider-range" ).slider()` and `$('#back-button').click()` on `(jQuery(document).ready(`

Comment: The order of the `js` files matter. What order you are having?

Comment: But as I was saying, on the landing page the slider works no problem. I tried accordion too. And on the second page it's just text all over the page, no accordion + `$(...).accordion is not a function(…)`

Comment: @Budbreaker.. I might anyhow need to see what you are actually doing... Otherwise it is very difficult to answer precisely. But your issue is basically because of above thing which you are missing..

Comment: @gurupasad-rao how can I show you ? Unfortunately, it's on localhost, but I can show you chunks of code anywhere you want

Comment: Are you having teamviewer?

Comment: Mail me @ kshkrao3@gmail.com